# How to get EAGLContext from UIWebView

Tags: ios, opengl-es, uiwebview, webgl, augmented-reality

I am trying to make a AR application which can run as H5 on iOS.

I use WebGL to draw 3D items, It is good.
I use DeviceOrientationEvent to get device Motion to control virtual camera in 3D, It is good.

I Know, till now, H5 on iOS can not support to show camera video stream.

I want to use hybrid way to solve this problem.

I write native code to get camera video stream, and set frame data into OpenGL as Y-plane Texture and UV-plan Texture.

then, I try to visit these Textures in my WebGL shader code.It is not good.

as far as I google, In iOS native code, only if EAGLContext object init with sharegroup, the OpenGL commands make sense.

```
- (instancetype) initWithAPI:(EAGLRenderingAPI) api sharegroup:(EAGLSharegroup*) sharegroup
```

so, If my hybrid way to do WebAR possible, the key point is **How to get EAGLContext from UIWebView**.

Anyone can show me your idea?